# How to set 3 month subscriptions for a in-product in android?

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm implementing in-app purchase function in my app which will have both managed and subscriptions in-app products.But my requirement is to have 3 month subsription. But in google play developer console there are only two way of subscriptions i.e Monthly and Yearly. Can anybody guide how to set 3 month subscriptions for a product.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this ?